# Angular JS add space/special character after currency filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How could I add a space/special character after the "₹".

Expected output:₹ 49

Current output:₹49

HTML -  **{{cart.getTotalPrice() | currency:"₹"}}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve with the currency filter. just use the number filter.

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <input class="tb" ng-model="numberInput" type="text" />            {{ "₹  "+(numberInput | number:2) }}              
  </div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('AddSiteURLCntr', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.numberInput = '1275.23';
   
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="AddSiteURLCntr">
      <input class="tb" ng-model="numberInput" type="text" />            {{ "₹  "+(numberInput | number:2) }}     
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

**View**

```
<span ng-bind="getCurrency(cart.getTotalPrice())"></span>&nbsp;
<span ng-bind="getElem(cart.getTotalPrice())"></span>
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.getCurrency = function (item) {
    return ($filter('currency')(item,'₹')).substring(0,1);
 }

 $scope.getElem = function (item) {
    return ($filter('currency')(item,'₹')).substring(1,item.length);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="my-app">
<div ng-controller="my-controller">
 <input type="number" name="price" ng-model="totalPrice">
 <p>{{getTotalPrice() | currency : "&#8377;  "}}</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var app = angular.module("my-app",[]);
 app.controller("my-controller",function($scope){
  $scope.totalPrice = 0;
  $scope.getTotalPrice = function(){
   return $scope.totalPrice;
  }
 });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can achieve this with filter . See the code I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a space after symbol, like this

**HTML - {{cart.getTotalPrice() | currency:"₹ "}}**

and you will get your desired output...

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the currency filter creating your own filter...

```
angular.module('yourModuleName').filter('money', filter);

function filter($filter, $locale) {

  const formats = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS;

  return function(amount, currencySymbol) {

    if (!currencySymbol) currencySymbol = formats.CURRENCY_SYM + ' ';

    return $filter('currency')(amount, currencySymbol);
  };
}
```

Now, you can apply your new filter called 'money'...

```
<span>{{vm.contractedPrice | money}}</span>
```